# Adjust jQuery image pre-loader to fetch all files with a certain prefix

Tags: jquery, image, automation, preloader, prefix

I'm starting out, I'm sorry for my ignorance...

I'd like to preload all image files in a mixed folder with the '_' prefix (_1.gif, _x.jpg, etc.).

Is there a way to incorporate this jQuery image preload script:

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
```

It seems like there's a way to slip something into this usage:

```
$(<--here?-->).preload();
```

I have this set for another script:

```
var prefix = "_";
```

But searching isn't getting me far...

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

The important consideration here is: how will the browser know what's in that directory? JavaScript running in the browser very purposefully does not have access to the files on your web server unless it makes a specific HTTP request.

If you know the names in advance, you can simply list them in your script:

```
$.preload(['_1.gif', '_2.gif', ...]);
```

If you do have a list of all these images you can filter that list first to get an array with just the ones that begin with `_`. (If that's where you're stuck, say so and we can be more specific.)

But if it's impractical or impossible to include all the image names in the script (e.g., because they're changed dynamically) you'd need to perform an AJAX request to the server asking for the list of images, and then use that list to handle the preloading. (And honestly, it's possible by the time you've done that you'd be better off just letting the images load naturally, depending on the size of the images and some other factors.)

Comment: Thanks Votey - that makes sense, thanks for taking the time to explain it! I can input the names in advance, I just wondered if there was a more elegant, automated way of pulling those that had the prefix. They're basically larger versions of preview images swapped out with another script so aren't visible or present until called. The names won't change dynamically, but the list will grow in the future and I thought there could be a shortcut (laaaazy!) instead of adding to the `$.preload(['_1.gif', '_2.gif', ...]);`. Thanks again for a good answer!